# Will 'forUpdate().fetchAny(condition)' lock only one row or multiple rows?

Tags: java, database, jooq

Recently i have switched to Java stack on new position and i got some troubles with Jooq which is used to access db

My question is:
will ForUpdate in the code below block only one row that satisfies *another_condition* and will be selected or multiple rows that satisfy *some_condition*

```sql
dslContext().select()
.from(my_table)
.where(some_condition)
.forUpdate()
.skipLocked()
.fetchAny(another_condition)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Client side `ResultSet` reading

The `ResultQuery.fetchAny()` method only defines client side behaviour between jOOQ and JDBC. It proceeds to fetch *at most* one record from the underlying JDBC `ResultSet`. In short:

- `ResultQuery.fetchAny()` fetches the first record (if available) from the `ResultSet`
- `ResultQuery.fetchOne()` fetches the first record (if available) from the `ResultSet` and attempts to fetch another one, in case of which it throws `TooManyRowsException`
- `ResultQuery.fetchSingle()` fetches the first record from the `ResultSet`, throws `NoDataFoundException` if no such record was found, and attempts to fetch another one, in case of which it throws `TooManyRowsException`

These methods do not communicate to the server anything about the intended result set usage, so the server doesn't *know* what you're planning to do.

#### Server side locking

This is unrelated to how you use SQL pessimistic locking clauses, such as `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`, which is an operation that happens purely on the server side, and ideally on the entire data set satisfying your `WHERE`, `LIMIT`, and other clauses. Even if this weren't the case, it's always better to be very explicit about everything you know about your SQL query *directly in SQL*.

So, since you're going to fetch only one record, why not tell the server, using `LIMIT 1`?

```java
dslContext()
    .select()
    .from(my_table)
    .where(some_condition)
    .limit(1)
    .forUpdate()
    .skipLocked()
    .fetchOne();
```

#### API side note

Note, there's no such thing as being able to pass *"another_condition"* to `fetchAny()`. You probably meant to stream the result and the use `Stream.filter()` on it, or something like that? But why would you lock N records and discard most of them?

Comment: what an answer, thank you really much, its clear to me now that limit(1) is actually what i need